# I can not show elements of my json - React

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I need to retrieve all the information from other fields, not just "Padre" and "Hijo" in the json. I also want to get information from fields like "Id" or "url". I think I can not get them back for the reduced function in componentWillMount, what if I need for "Padre" and "Hijo".

This is an example of my json.

```
{
  "Id": "114",
  "Description": "SALUD NORMAL",
  "Padre": "CRM",
  "Hijo": "Argumentarios",
  "URL": "www.test.com",
  "Closable": "1",
  "Autoload": "0",
  "Visible": "1"
 }
```

Nav would be the parent element and content his child, Menu. Menu is the one that creates a button for each of the "Padre" (this.props.menu) and "Hijo" (this.props.submenu) of the json.

This is my code.

```
class Nav extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            menuSubmenu:[],
            abrirSubmenu: false,
        }
        this.submenuClick = this.submenuClick.bind(this);
    }
    submenuClick() {
        this.setState(state => ({
            abrirSubmenu: !state.abrirSubmenu
          }));
        //alert('Click!')
    }
    componentWillMount(){
        fetch('fake.php')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(menuSubmenu =>{

            const PadreMap = menuSubmenu.reduce((acc, obj) => {
                if (!acc[obj.Padre]) {
                  acc[obj.Padre] = {
                    ...obj,
                    Hijo: [obj.Hijo],
                    Description: [obj.Description]
                  };
                } else {
                  !acc[obj.Padre].Hijo.includes(obj.Hijo) && acc[obj.Padre].Hijo.push(obj.Hijo);
                  //!acc[obj.Padre].Hijo.includes(obj.Hijo) && acc[obj.Padre].Hijo.push(obj.Description)
                }
                return acc;
              }, {});

                this.setState({
                        menuSubmenu: Object.keys(PadreMap).map((padre) => ({
                        menu: padre,
                        submenu: PadreMap[padre].Hijo,
                        id: PadreMap.Id,
                        descripcion: PadreMap[padre].Description,
                        url: PadreMap[padre].URL
                }))

            })
            console.log(PadreMap);
        })
    }

    render() {
        if (this.state.menuSubmenu.length > 0) {
          return(
            <nav className="nav">
                <div className="menu">
                    <ul className="list">
                        {this.state.menuSubmenu.map(datos => <Menu key={datos.id} menu={datos.menu} submenu={datos.submenu} descripcion={datos.descripcion} submenuClick={this.submenuClick} abrirSubmenu={this.state.abrirSubmenu}/>)}
                    </ul>
                    <div className="content-bnt">
                        <button id="desplegar" className='btn btn--rounded'>
                            <Icon icon="flecha" className='ico-flecha'/>
                        </button>
                    </div>  
                </div>
            </nav>
          );
        }
        return (<p>Cargando usuarios...</p>);
    }
}

class Menu extends Component{
    render(){
        return (
            <li key={this.props.id} className="list__item">
                <button title={this.props.menu} id={"mn-" + this.props.menu} className="desplegable" onClick={this.props.submenuClick}><Icon icon="auriculares" className='ico-auriculares'/>{this.props.menu}</button>
            {
            this.props.abrirSubmenu
                ? (
                <div id="sb-crm" className="submenu">
                    {this.props.submenu.map(hijo => <h3 className="nav--title"><Icon icon="descargar" className='ico-descargar'/>{hijo}</h3>)}
                    <ul className="list">
                        <li className="list__item">
                            {this.props.descripcion.map(tercerNivel => <a href={this.props.url} title={this.props.descripcion}>{tercerNivel}</a>)}
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                )
                : (
                null
                )
            }
            </li>
        )
    }
}

export default Nav;
```

I need to be able to use all the information of the json, not just "Padre" and "Hijo". I also need the information to be grouped by his "Padre"

Answer (score 0):

This snippet should be suitable:

```
this.setState(
  {
    menuSubmenu: Object.keys(PadreMap).map((padre) => {
      const {Padre, Hijo, ...rest} = PadreMap[padre];
      return {
        menu: padre,
        submenu: Hijo,
        ...rest
      }
    })
  }
)
```

Comment: Hello @xadm I have answered in another comment. I'm sorry but i have an error with your code.

Comment: provide results of `console.log(PadreMap)` and `console.log(this.state)` (in `render()`)